# Define tsvector type column for a model

Tags: go, go-gorm

I would like to add a column of type `tsvector` in postgres by defining a field in a model struct. It would look sort of like:

```
type Issue struct {
  ...
  TSV tsvector `json:"tsv"`
}
```

The reason is that I would like to use gorm's `AutoMigrate` to keep the tables up-to-date while developing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type Address struct {
    TSV string         `gorm:"type:tsvector"`
}
```

Also refer  https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/dialects/postgres/postgres.go, it should works similar like hstore, jsonb

Comment: Thanks. I suggested an edit to make the answer a bit more relevant to the specificities of the question.